# Getting the X oldest items from a HashSet?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a HashSet that holds a collection of "Item" class instances, in that class Item I have a DateTime 'AddedAt', I am trying to get the X amount of oldest items, judging by the AddedAt in the class, but I don't know what to do next, can someone help?

This is as far as I got...

```
public List<Item> GetOldestItems(int count)
{
    List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    foreach (Item item in _itemsHashSet)
    {

    }

    return items;
}
```

Here is the Item class:

```
internal class Item
{
    public DateTime AddedAt;

    public Item()
    {
        AddedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the "added at" the time the item was *added to the hash set*?  If so, then what happens when one item is added to two sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy()` returns the enumeration in "lowest first" order for whichever property value the selector lambda returns (`AddedAt`, in our case). Then you can call `Take(count)` to grab the first `n` items from that re-ordered enumeration.

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetOldestItems(int count)
{
    return _itemsHashSet.OrderBy(i => i.AddedAt).Take(count);
}
```

If the caller wants `List<Item>`, the caller can call:

```
var list = GetOldestItems(12).ToList();
```

---

The difference in thinking between this and @RacilHilan's equally correct answer is that we often chain a number of LINQ calls without ever creating a collection: `OrderBy()` above doesn't return a collection; it returns `IOrderedEnumerable<Item>`, for example, and `Take(n)` returns `IEnumerable<Item>`. So it's in the spirit of LINQ to assume that the caller may do some further LINQ operations on the enumeration we return. Additionally, we may actually want to defer execution. Perhaps you'll want to keep the result around and re-evaluate it every five minutes. If you haven't frozen the current results in a list, that enumeration my method returns will *requery* `_itemsHashSet` every time you enumerate it, so you'll always get the 12 oldest items, but they might be twelve *different* oldest items. Cool stuff.

```
var x = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>(
    GetOldestItems(12).Select(x => x.AddedAt).Reverse().Take(5));
```

However, for your purposes, it's wildly unlikely that creating one extra List along the way is going to be a career-ending disaster.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to sort the list first and then then select the first "count" items by index. Alternatively, you can use LINQ to do the job for you:

```
public List<Item> GetOldestItems(int count)
{
    return _itemsHashSet.OrderBy(i => i.AddedAt).Take(count).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A HashSet is not the best type of collection for this type of lookup, when using a hashset you would need to sort the collection descending as a IEnumerable on the AddedAt property (a `O(n log n)` operation) then take the first x values of that sorted enumerable (see the other answers for implementations of that).

If you are going to be doing this operation a lot compared to adding new elements to the hash set a way to do this is use a [`SortedSet<Item>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1) with a comparer that sorts by the date. This it does slow down your hash set lookups and insertions from `O(1)` to `O(log n)` but it speeds up your lookup of the top items to `O(1)` because no sorting needs to be done before taking the first x items.

```
private sealed class AddedAtComparer : Comparer<Item>
{
    public override int Compare(Item x, Item y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return 0;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, y)) return 1;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, x)) return -1;
        return x.AddedAt.CompareTo(y.AddedAt);
    }
}

private SortedSet<Item> _itemsHashSet = new SortedSet<Item>(new AddedAtComparer());
public List<Item> GetOldestItems(int count)
{
    return _itemsHashSet.Take(count).ToList();
}
```

The `.ToList()` makes this a `O(k)` operation where k is the count of items to take. If you change your code to the following `GetOldestItems` would be a `O(1)` operation because the take operation is deferred till you need to enumerate over it.

```
private SortedSet<Item> _itemsHashSet = new SortedSet<Item>(new AddedAtComparer());
public IEnumerable<Item> GetOldestItems(int count)
{
    return _itemsHashSet.Take(count);
}
```

Comment: O(n + k log k) where k is the amount taken if the `Take` is order-by–aware.

Comment: @JonHanna it is not aware, [the code for it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,9f32b11a889f3aa5) shows it is a simple foreach loop that goes over the IEnumerable with no intelligence.

Comment: The NetFX version isn't, the CoreFX version is.